# Cron job in strapi V3 does not get triggered when a method from strapi services is called

Tags: node.js, strapi, node-schedule

```
config/functions/cron.js

async function logger() {
    console.log("Hello, Im Async");     
}

module.exports = {

  '*/10 * * * * *': async () => {
    console.log("Before);
    await strapi.services.collectionName.someMethodName();
    console.log("After);
},

  '*/10 * * * * *': async () => {
    await logger();
  },

};
```

In the example above logger gets called properly. But someMethodName doesn't get called at all. Before and After are also not printed. I dont know what is wrong and how to check it.

Same code works in staging site but not on production server.
I dont understand what is happening and how to solve this.

Does anyone know a solution to this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. Posting it here so that it will help someone else in the future.

Time format for both of the cron tasks is the same. When I checked the list of active cron in the strapi config; there was only one cron task available. It seems that as the key for the export was same, second entry was overriding the first one. When I wrote diff time formats for diff task, list of active cron jobs showed all the cron tasks.

Below commands will help you check the list of active cron tasks.

```
npm run strapi console 
const strapi = require('strapi');
strapi().config
```